# Choose $m$ out of $n$ distributions s.t. the union of them likely contains top $k$ elements

Tags: probability, distributions, optimization, quantiles

I have $n$ sets of items. Each item in each set has a certain score. I want to select top $k$ items out of all available (i.e., out of the union of $n$ sets). However, explicitly calculating the union is going to take a humongous time, the sets are huge.

Instead, I decided to pursue an approximate approach: I only want something close to the top $k$ items, with a high probability of overlap.
I'm only going to look at $m \ll n$ sets, and hope that these sets contain most of the highest scores across my entire collection.

The question is now: how to choose these $m$ "probably best" sets.
One approach that I want to try is the following: sample some items from each of the $n$ sets (this can be done pretty fast), creating $n$ approximate distributions. Now I want to use the information about these $n$ distributions to select $m$ best ones. However, I cannot figure out an optimal selection criterion.

For instance, it's clearly impractical to choose the ones with $m$ highest maxima if $k < m$. Even if $k \ge m$, most of the probability mass of some distributions can be concentrated in their higher ranges, so some of the selected sets will not contribute anything to the top $k$.
It looks like the "right" answer would analyze the actual distributions (their medians, quantiles, etc.), but I cannot derive a good precise formula.